# How do I convert a DXF mesh to a solid surface?

Tags: mesh, nurbs-surface

I want to import a DXF mesh, and export a solid model for 3D printing. I need to convert the DXF mesh to a solid surface (and then extrude it). Can Blender do this?

Comment: What's the type of the entities forming the mesh ? MESH, FACE3D, POLYFACE, POLYLINE3D, ... ?

Comment: No idea! But seem to have solved my problem using the Boolean Union modifier. Thanks for your reply.